# Weaving AspectJ aspects included in an Eclipse 3.7 plugin project

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, aspectj, eclipse-pde

### Goal

I am building an Eclipse plugin targeting the 3.7 environment and would like to include an aspect in the plugin that provides advice on code that is also in the plugin.

### Setup

I have been trying to follow along with the spirit of these guidelines as best I can considering the apparent differences between 3.4 and 3.7: http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/incubator/aspects/equinox-aspects-quick-start.php

Here is what I have so far:

1. A plugin project with the aspect and some source.
2. The plugin project has been converted to an AspectJ project, which triggered Eclipse to automatically add `org.aspectj.runtime (1.6.12)` to the plugin's dependencies.
3. I checked "Reexport this dependency" on the `org.aspectj.runtime` dependency in my plugin configuration.
4. I defined the aspect in an *aop.xml* in my META-INF directory.
5. My MANIFEST.MF has an `Export-Package` entry on the package that the aspect is in.
6. My run configuration includes the following plugins and start levels:

   - `org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj` (start level of 1)
   - `org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook` (start level of default which is 4)
   - `org.aspectj.runtime` (start level of 1)
   - `org.aspectj.weaver` (start level of 1)

### Current results

I see lines in the console that look like this, but it appears that this processing occurs the first time each class is classloaded.

`[com.my.traceeditor] info processing reweavable type com.my.util.ByteUtil: com\my\util\ByteUtil.java`

No advice is being applied.  Is it possible the weaver isn't weaving early enough?  What to do?

Comment: I should also mention that a JUnit test written in the same project that is designed to test the aspect works as expected -- advice is applied.  The pointcut definition is definitely not the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to advise methods using Equinox AspectJ from aspects in another bundle and somehow the aspects were not being honored. Having a run configuration as described in #6 help fixed my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are writing an aspect that is only to be applied in the same bundle, then you don't need equinox weaving.  That is only for cross-bundle weaving.  You can remove the dependency on the weaving plugins as long as you make sure that your bundle is using compile-time weaving.